# Modify column value Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Hello I have made a Trigger it compiles

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER livraisonfinie

    BEFORE  UPDATE  ON Expedition
    FOR EACH ROW 

    DECLARE

    BEGIN   

        IF :NEW.date_livraison <> TO_DATE('3000/01/01 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
        THEN
            INSERT INTO Commande (etat) VALUES ('livree');

            DELETE FROM cmdalivrer CMD  WHERE :NEW.numero_commande=CMD.id_cmd WHERE :NEW.numero_commande= Commande.numero_commande;;

        END IF ;
    END;
    /
```

When I try to update a value of expedition table I get this error

```
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("HAMZA"."COMMANDE"."NUMERO_COMMANDE")
ORA-06512: at "HAMZA.LIVRAISONFINIE", line 10
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'HAMZA.LIVRAISONFINIE'
```

And I have used this update request but not sure if I have to use INSERT INTO or UPDATE and how corretly even after reading many manuals.

Here's the table

```
Expedition(Id_Expedition ,#id_chauffeur,#Immatriculation, #Id_Itineraire,Date_Deb_Expedition , Date_Livraison) 
Commande (numero_commande,Date_commande,adresse_livraison,id_part,ville_livraison,code_postal_livraison,etat,id_expedition)
```

EDIT: I solved it by adding  "where :NEW.numero_commande= Commande.numero_commande;" to my trigger. 
Thanks

Comment: Show us structure of the table COMMANDE because that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is NOT NULL constraint on column `NUMERO_COMMANDE` in table `COMMANDE`.
More on this constraint you can find here:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_notnull.asp

> By default, a table column can hold NULL values.
>
> **SQL NOT NULL Constraint** 
>   The NOT NULL constraint enforces a column to
>   NOT accept NULL values.
>
> The NOT NULL constraint enforces a field to always contain a value.
>   This means that you cannot insert a new record, or update a record
>   without adding a value to this field.

Either provide a value for this field in your trigger:

```
INSERT INTO Commande (etat,NUMERO_COMMANDE) 
VALUES ('livree', some-value-for-numero-commande-column);
```

or remove NOT NULL constraint on this column from the table.